# Is saying "may have" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, modal-verbs

I believe I've heard that might is the past tense of may. So you should say might have never may have.

Comment: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=1683

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this specific aspect of the may/might debate has been asked about in previous questions.

Catherine Soanes at [ODO Blog](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/04/may-or-might-whats-the-difference/) has this to say:

> Basically, *might* is the past tense of *may*. It therefore seems
>   logical for grammatical sticklers to argue that if you’re talking
>   about a possible situation in the present or the future, you should
>   always use the present tense, *may*:
>
> *If you’re feeling queasy, you may eat less and lose weight.*
>
> And, equally, if you’re referring to something which could have been
>   the case in the past, the past tense, *might*, is said (by the
>   grammatically orthodox) to be correct:
>
> *For all we know, she might have been undergoing counselling.*
>
> However, people don’t often make this distinction in today’s English,
>   and it’s generally acceptable to use either *may* [or] *might* to talk
>   about the present/future or the past:
>
> Present or future event
>
> √   *She thinks she may be going crazy.*
>
> √   *She thinks she might be going crazy.*
>
> Past event
>
> √  *I might have forgotten to mention it at the time.*
>
> √  *I may have forgotten to mention it at the time.*

Answer (score 0):

It’s all about **dialect variation**:

Dialects A and B are differentiated by reference to constructions like:

1. *I thought it might rain before we got home*.
2. *I thought it may rain before we got home*.

In the older Dialect A (which I speak) [2] is ungrammatical (just like **I thought I can finish the book before I got home*): [1], with "might" is required. In Dialect B, [2] is possible as well as [1]. In Dialect A, "might" is undoubtedly the preterite counterpart of "may", just as "could" is of "can" because it is the form required in backshift. In Dialect B there's no basis for retaining (from earlier stages of the language) the analysis of "might" as the preterite of "may": it must be a distinct lexeme.

One factor facilitating this linguistic change is that "might" even in Dialect A is hardly used in the primary sense of the preterite, to indicate past time: we are more likely to say "was/were allowed" rather than "might" for past time permission, e.g. He told me "I/we might go")